# Parent node is null after first append operation

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the following function to render the options available in a combobox:

```
var optionsListElement = element.find('div.combobox-list'),
itemsElement = optionsListElement.find('ul.items-list');

function renderOptions(items) {
    var parentElement = itemsElement.parent();

    if (!items || items.length == 0) {
        itemsElement = itemsElement.append($(
            '<li class="no-bullet">No Option Available</li>'));
    } else {
        if (!scope.hasColumns) {
            items.forEach(function (item, i) {
                innerScope = createInnerScope({
                    item: item,
                    $first: i == 0,
                    $index: i,
                    $even: i % 2 == 0,
                    $odd: i % 2 != 0,
                    $last: i == item.length - 1
                });

                transclude(innerScope, function (rowTemplate, transcludeScope) {
                    // If there is not transclude rowTemplate, use default
                    if (rowTemplate.length == 0 || rowTemplate.length == 1 && rowTemplate[0].nodeType == 3 && rowTemplate[0]) {
                        rowTemplate = angular.element(
                            '<span title="{{ getText(item) }}" \
                                                        >{{ getText(item) }}\
                                                    </span>');
                    }

                    itemsElement.append(
                        $compile(angular.element(
                            '<li ng-click="focusAndSelectOption(item)"\
                                                        ng-class-even="\'even\'" ng-class-odd="\'odd\'"\
                                                        ng-class="{ selected: isSelected(item), focused: isFocused($index) }">\
                                                    </li>').append(rowTemplate))(transcludeScope)
                    );
                });
            });
        }
    }

    parentElement.append(itemsElement);
}
```

For the first call (with no `items`), the function works as expected and binds the `li` with text `No Option Available` to the `itemsElement`. The `parentElement` seems to hold the correct target `div` to append. But on any subsequent calls, the `parent()` returns a `null` and `parentElement` is not available to append the options.

The `div` structure consuming this function is something like the following:

```
<div class="combobox-list" style="visibility:hidden" >
    <ul class="items-list" ></ul>
</div>
```

I'm just trying to bind the `li` items to the `ul` and there are few attribute directives bound to the `ul` so I have to keep it out of the code. Can somebody help me with this issue?

Comment: The issue was another function that was cleaning up all the `ul` elements. So this becomes irrelevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was another function that was cleaning up all the ul elements. So this becomes irrelevant